# Logout code not executing at all. php

Tags: php

Here is the code

I dont know whats wrong with it.

```
<?php
       //Logout code
       //Starting Session
       session_start();
       //Include
       include ("includes/mass.php");
       //Check if the user is logged in
       $username = $_SESSION['username'];
       $logged_in_query = "SELECT * FROM    user WHERE loggedin='1' AND    username='$username'";
       $check_if_logged_in =    mysql_query($logged_in_query);
       if (isset($username))

    {       while ($row =    mysql_fetch_array($check_if_logged_in))

            {
                $logged_in = $row['loggedin'];

                if ($logged_in == 1)

                    {
                    //User becomes logged out on database records

                    $sql_logout = "UPDATE user SET loggedin='0' WHERE loggedin='1' AND    username='$username'";

                    $logout_query = mysql_query($logout_query);

                    //Logout page

                    session_destroy();

                    echo "You have been logged out.","<br>"."<a    href='index.php'>Click Here To Go    Back</a>";
                    }
                            }
                }                else

    {
                                echo"You are not logged in"."<br><a href='register.php'>Click    To Sign Up</a>";
                            }           
         ?>
```

Comment: Nothing. Im just getting a blank screen. :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a mysql link object (from mysql_connect() / mysql_select_db() ?) From your comments below, it doesn't sound that way.

This SQL is wrong:

```
$sql_logout = "UPDATE user WHERE loggedin='1' AND username='$username'";
```

Should be:

```
$sql_logout = "UPDATE user SET loggedin=0 WHERE loggedin='1' AND username='$username'";
```

?

You probably also mean to be using mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array().

This line:

```
$logout_query = mysql_query($logout_query);
```

Should be

```
$logout_query = mysql_query($sql_logout);
```

Put in your correct mysql connection and db information and try to run this. Please post the output.

```
<?php
//Logout code
//Starting Session
session_start();

echo "hello<br />";

//Include
include ("includes/mass.php");

echo "no problem in mass.php!<br />";

// FILL ME IN
$my_link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password, TRUE);
mysql_select_db('your_db', $link);

//Check if the user is logged in
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$logged_in_query = "SELECT loggedin FROM user WHERE loggedin='1' AND username='$username'";
echo $logged_in_query . "<br />";

$check_if_logged_in = mysql_query($logged_in_query, $my_link);
var_dump(mysql_num_rows($check_if_logged_in));

if (isset($username))
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_if_logged_in))
    {
        var_dump($row);

        $logged_in = $row['loggedin'];

        if ($logged_in == 1)
        {
            //User become logged out on database records
            $sql_logout = "UPDATE user SET loggedin=0 WHERE loggedin='1' AND username='$username'";
            $logout_query = mysql_query($sql_logout, $my_link);

            //Logout page
            session_destroy();
            echo "You have been logged out.","<br>"."<a href='index.php'>Click Here To Go Back</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo"You are not logged in"."<br><a href='register.php'>Click To Sign Up</a>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: No there is still an issue. The if statement code seems to be getting completely ignored. :(

Comment: Just realised that the else statement needs to be outside the if too. Hasn't solved the problem though. :) Just my own mistake :)

Comment: @Tapha: What does mysql_num_rows($check_if_logged_in) return?

Comment: @Tapha: Do you have a mysql link object? try $check_if_logged_in = mysql_query($logged_in_query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: At the very least it should be echoing the else statement. :( its completely ignoring the code from if and downwards. (UPDATEd CODE).

Comment: @Tapha: Please see the code block I added to the bottom of my answer, what's the output from that?

Comment: @Tapha: Did you change the mysql_connect() function to use your real data? Please post EVERYTHING (except for sensitive stuff) it is printing to the screen.

Comment: @Tapha: We don't really know what the issue is..some debug output would be nice..

Answer (score 1):

what you have written is very bad code. i would suggest you do like this
1. create a session in the login page once their username and password matches with the entry in the db
2. destroy that session when they say log out.

your implementation of checking the user using db is not scalable. everytime it gets executed and its not the right idea of doing it.

Comment: Im entrigued. I thought this way would simply add a layer of security to it. Could you elaborate on how specifically it can prevent scaling. I would like to know.

Comment: assume, 1000 users accessing your site. they all logged in. u have to do 1000 updates for intial login and 1000 updates for logout which is costlier. also 1000 queries for every request. think about 1million users... will your stuff work? to make sure, try the performance tests using Jmeter. you will know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
    <?php
    //Logout code
    //Starting Session
    session_start();
    //Include
    include ("includes/mass.php");
    //Check if the user is logged in
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    if (isset($username))
    {
     $logged_in_query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE loggedin='1' AND username='".$username."' LIMIT 1";
     $check_if_logged_in = mysql_query($logged_in_query);
     $logged_in = mysql_fetch_field($check_if_logged_in);

      if ($logged_in == 1)
      {
       //User becomes logged out on database records

       $sql_logout = "UPDATE user SET loggedin='0' WHERE loggedin='1' AND username='".$username."' LIMIT 1";

       $logout_query = mysql_query($logout_query);
       if ($logout_query)
       {
        //Logout page

        session_destroy();
        echo "You have been logged out.","<br>"."<a href='index.php'>Click Here To Go Back</a>";
       }
       else
       {
        //Couldn't update the user table to set your login status.
        echo "MYSQL Error, please contact admin LO-2";
        exit();
       }
      }
      else
      {
       echo "You are not logged in"."<br><a href='register.php'>Click To Sign Up</a>";
      }
     }
     else
     {
      echo "You are not logged in"."<br><a href='register.php'>Click To Sign Up</a>";
     }
?>
```

Not tested

Max